# How to suppress python3 warning with -Wi cli flag: `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:87: RequestsDependencyWarning`

Tags: python-3.x

```
$ uname -a; python3 --version; bash --version|head -1
Linux 6.5.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Mar 12 10:22:43 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Python 3.10.12
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

The correct answer to this question is to **sweep the specific problem the warning is warning about under the rug** and suppress the warning.* As python3 is supposed to be able to be selective about the warnings it suppresses, **I only want RequestsDependencyWarning warnings suppressed.**

The cli error:

```
$ python3 -W ignore::\ RequestsDepedencyWarning script.py
Invalid -W option ignored: unknown warning category: 'RequestsDepedencyWarning'
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:87: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.5) or chardet (2.3.0) doesn't match a supported version!
  warnings.warn("urllib3 ({}) or chardet ({}) doesn't match a supported "
```

From man python3,

```
"   -W argument
              Warning  control.  Python's  warning  machinery  by  default  prints warning messages to
              sys.stderr.

              The simplest settings apply a particular action unconditionally to all warnings  emitted
              by a process (even those that are otherwise ignored by default):

                -Wdefault  # Warn once per call location
                -Werror    # Convert to exceptions
                -Walways   # Warn every time
                -Wmodule   # Warn once per calling module
                -Wonce     # Warn once per Python process
                -Wignore   # Never warn

              The  action names can be abbreviated as desired and the interpreter will resolve them to
              the appropriate action name. For example, -Wi is the same as -Wignore .

              The full form of argument is: action:message:category:module:lineno

              Empty fields match all values; trailing empty fields may be omitted. For example -W  ig‐
              nore::DeprecationWarning ignores all DeprecationWarning warnings."
```

from https://peps.python.org/pep-0230/ the command-line syntax is

`-Waction[:message[:category[:module[:lineno]]]]`

As such I expect that `$ python3 -W ignore::RequestsDependencyWarning script.py` will suppress the warning with the message `RequestsDependencyWarning` —which it does not.

I've tried some other things that come from examples:

```
19967  python3 -W ignore::\ RequestsDependencyWarning script.py
19968  python3 -W ignore::\RequestsDependencyWarning script.py
19969  python3 -W ignore::RequestsDependencyWarning script.py
19970  python3 -Wi::RequestsDependencyWarning script.py
19971  python3 -Wi::' RequestsDependencyWarning' script.py
19972  python3 -Wi::" RequestsDependencyWarning" script.py
19973  python3 -Wi::" RequestsDependencyWarning:" script.py
19974  python3 -Wi::"RequestsDependencyWarning:" script.py
19975  python3 -Wi::'RequestsDependencyWarning:' script.py
19976  python3 -Wi::'RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3' script.py
19977  python3 -Wi::'RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (2.2.1)' script.py
20011  python3 -W ignore::87
20012  python3 -W ignore::87 script.py
20013  python3 -W ignore::Requests* script.py
20014  python3 -W ignore::Requests script.py
20015  python3 -W ignore:: Requests script.py
20016  python3 -W ignore::\ Requests script.py
20017  python3 -W ignore::\ RequestsDepedencyWarning script.py
20018  python3 -W ignore::DeprecationWarning script.py
20019  python3 -W ignore::DeprecationWarning script.py
20020  python3 -W ignore::DeprecationWarning: script.py
20021  python3 -W ignore::DeprecationWarning:RequestsDependencyWarning script.py
20022  python3 -W ignore::DeprecationWarning:RequestsDependencyWarning: script.py
20023  python3 -W ignore::DeprecationWarning script.py
20031  python3 -Wi:::Deprecation script.py
20032  python3 -Wi::Deprecation script.py
20033  python3 -Wi::Requests script.py
20034  python3 -Wi:Requests script.py
20035  python3 -Wi:RequestsDependencyWarning script.py
20036  python3 -Wi::RequestsDependencyWarning script.py
20037  python3 -Wi:::RequestsDependencyWarning script.py
```

and python3 continues to mock me with its intransigent warnings that I very much want to stop.

How do I force python3 to suppress that warning with a -W flag and argument?

**NB: there are a bunch of answers on how to *fix* the underlying problem if that is what *you* are looking to do.  I just want to hide it so I can continue on without seeing it in blissful ignorance.*

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, we're trying to get the cli input in the form of

`python3 -Waction[:message[:category[:module[:lineno]]]] script.py`

We can reduce `python3 -W ignore:` to `python3 -Wi:`.

To some extent, we can "diagram the sentence" of the specific error:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:87: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.5) or chardet (2.3.0) doesn't match a supported version!
  warnings.warn("urllib3 ({}) or chardet ({}) doesn't match a supported "
```

- `message` of the warning is `urllib (1.26.5 or chardet (2.3.0) doesn't match a supported version!`
- `category`: testing of the warning categories showed that
  "RequestsDependencyWarning" is **not** a `DeprecationWarning` but
  rather a `Warning`**
- `module` of this warning is the dist-package in question, `requests`
- `lineno` is `87`

As such, the most complete -Wi statement I can give is:

`$ python3 -Wi:urllib3\ \(1.26.5\)\ or\ chardet\ \(2.3.0\)\ doesn\'t\ match\ a\ supported\ version\!:Warning:requests:87 script.py`

I assume there's a way to quote that without \s, but I couldn't figure it out, perhaps someone can update this answer.

Some other things that will work to suppress this specific error:

```
$ python3 -Wi:u:::87 #this is probably an insufficiently specific minimum.
$ python3 -Wi:urllib3:87 #more specific
$ python3 -Wi:'urllib3 (1.26.5)':::87 #probably specific enough
$ python3 -Wi:'urllib3 (1.26.5)':Warning::87
```

**From a 2000 document on python warning framework, "the following warnings category classes are currently defined:

> `Warning` – this is the base class of all warning category classes and **it itself a subclass of Exception**
>
> `UserWarning` – the default category for warnings.warn()
>
> `DeprecationWarning` – base category for warnings about deprecated features
>
> `SyntaxWarning` – base category for warnings about dubious syntactic features
>
> `RuntimeWarning` – base category for warnings about dubious runtime features"

(from: https://peps.python.org/pep-0230/ emphasis added)